# How to debug this Matlab code to model glider descent?

Tags: matlab, function, loops, plot, ode45

I have this Matlab project but for some reason I just cannot stop thinking about it because I could not get it to work.

***Objective:***

This is a MATLAB script that would calculate the change of pressure, temperature and density of a glider that is being dropped from 10000 feet. As it falls, we want to use those new values calculated and then plugged in a function that has 4 equations that need to be differentiated at every point using ode45 as well as the new values of P T and Rho.

***Here is the main code:***

```
% HouseKeeping:

clc
clear all
close all

% Constants:
S = 232;                                         % ft^2
Cd0 = 0.02;
K = 0.07;
W = 11000;                                       % lbf
Cl_max = sqrt(Cd0/K);
Cd_max = 2*K*Cl_max^2;
Rho_10000 = .001756;                             % slugs/ ft^3

%Initial conditions:
t = 0;                                           % Sec
x = 0;                                           % ft
h = 10000;                                       % ft
v = sqrt((2*W)/(Rho_10000*S*Cl_max));            %ft/s
gamma = -Cd_max/Cl_max; 

% Find Endurance:
V_RD= sqrt((2*W)/(S* Rho_10000* sqrt(3*Cd0/K)));
RD= V_RD/((sqrt(3*Cd0/K))/(2*Cd0))  ;            % ft/s
Endurcance= h/RD;                                % 958.3515 sec

% Sea Level values:
TSL = 518.69;                                    % Rankine
PSL = 2116.199414;                               % lbs/ft^2
RhoSL = 0.0023769;                          % slugs/ft^3

while h > 0

    tspan = [t t+1];
    i=1;
    X = [x;h;v;gamma;Rho_10000];
    Time(i)= t;

    % Calling ODE45:
    [F] = ode45(@ D,tspan, X)

    % Hight Varying Parameters:
    T = TSL - 0.00356616*h;
    P = (1.137193514E-11)*(T)^5.2560613;
    Rho = (RhoSL * TSL / PASL)*(P / T);
    a = 49.0214 * (T)^.5;

    H_Del(i) = (-Cd_max/Cl_max)*(plotted_x(i))+10000;
    V_Del(i) = sqrt((2*W)/(Rho*S*Cl_max));
    Gamma_Del(i) = -Cd_max/Cl_max;
    i= i+1;

    X = [ x ; H_Del(i); V_Del(i); Gamma_Del(i); Rho];

end



% Plots:

%1
figure (1)
plot(F(:,1),'-r',F(:,3),'-b')
title('Velocity vs Distance');
xlabel('x (ft)');
ylabel('v (ft/s)');


%2 
Figure (2)
plot(F(:,1),'-r',F(:,2),'-b')
title('Altitude vs Distance ');
xlabel('x (ft)');
ylabel('h (ft)');


%3
figure (3)
plot(F(:,1),'-r',F(:,4),'-b')
title('Gamma vs Distance');
xlabel('x (ft)');
ylabel('Gamma (rad)');

%4
figure (4)
plot(t,'-r',F(:,3),'-b')
title('Velocity vs Time');
xlabel(' t (s)');
ylabel('v  (ft/s)');

%5
figure (5)
plot(t,'-r',F(:,1),'-b')
title(' Distance vs Time ');
xlabel('t (s)');
ylabel('x (ft)');


%6
figure (6)
plot(t,'-r',F(:,4),'-b')
title('Gamma vs Time ');
xlabel('t (s)');
ylabel('Gamma (rad)');

%7 
figure (7)
plot(t,'-r',F(:,3),'-b')
title('Velocity vs Time');
xlabel('t (s)');
ylabel('V (ft/s)');
```

***Here is the Function***

```
function [F] = D(X)

% Constants:
S = 232;                                         % ft^2
Cd0 = 0.02;
K = 0.07;
W = 11000;                                       % lbf
Cl_max = sqrt(Cd0/K);
Cd_max = 2*K*Cl_max^2;
Rho_10000 = .001756;                             % slugs/ ft^3

% Initial conditions:
t = 0;                                           % Sec
x = 0;                                           % ft
h = 10000;                                       % ft
v = sqrt((2*W)/(Rho_10000*S*Cl_max));            % ft/s
gamma = -Cd_max/Cl_max; 
g= 32.2;                                         % ft/s^2

% Equations:
X_Pr = X(3)*cos(X(4));
H_Pr = X(3)*sin(X(4));
V_Pr = (-32.2./W)*(0.5*X(5)*Cd_max*S*X(3)^2 + W*sin(X(4)));
G_Pr = (32.2./(W*X(3)))*(0.5*X(5)*Cl_max*S*X(3)^2 - W*cos(X(4)));

F = [X_Pr;H_Pr;V_Pr;G_Pr];
```

I am not very good with Matlab but I did my very best! I went to my professors for help but they said they were too busy. I even stalked every senior I knew and they all said they did not know how to do it. My next project will be assigned soon and I think that if I cannot do this then I would not be able to do the next one.

Comment: `I could not get it to work???` - explain the problem!  syntax error, run error? unexpected results?  Don't just through out code, and expect us to do the work for you.

Comment: Thank you sir, and I sincerely apologize for making you think that .. as I mentioned earlier I have been working on this everyday for almost a month now, I know I am lacking and I obviously do not know how to make this work, but I genuinely tried! you can blame me for my incapability but you cannot say that I am just throwing it out there for people to do it for me because it is not true. And to answer your question it is ALL of them. I am not a programmer and I have no past experience with MATLAB, and all of a sudden we have to use it for something so complicated and expected to get it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code produces the following error:

> Error using main>D
>
> Too many input arguments.

This means that ode45 tries to call your provided function `D` with too many input arguments. You should check the desired `odefun` format in the [`ode45`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html#inputarg_odefun) documentation: `dydt = odefun(t,y)`

So, you should change your function declaration of `D` to

```
function [F] = D(t, X)
```

This should solve your first problem, but a following error pops up:

> D returns a vector of length 4, but the length of initial conditions
>   vector is 5. The vector returned by D and the initial conditions
>   vector must have the same number of elements.

Again, you should check the [`ode45`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html#inputarg_odefun) documentation. Your function should return the derivatives of all your input variables `X`: `F = dX/dt`. You should also return the derivate of the fifth element `Rho_10000`.

Next, I got some error about undefined variables such as `PASL`. Probably because you did not post your full code.

Besides of the errors, you should really check your code again. You have written an infinite while loop `while h > 0`. You never change `h` in the loop, nor you use the output of `ode45` in your loop. Furthermore you always overwrite your `i` and `X` value at the beginning of the loop, which is probably not what you want.

*This is not a full answer to your question, but I hope you will be able to continue and post smaller, well defined problems, instead of one big problem which is very difficult to answer completely.*

Comment: Thank you so much Sir. This was very helpful! thank you for taking the time to look it my script, it means so much to me. I will try again using everything I learned from you. Thank you!